# I want to retrieve the 'totalPages' on the image of the Backend Spring data JSON response to Frontend Angular

Tags: angular, spring-data-jpa

Here is my code

**component.ts:**

```
doSearch() {

this.classeService.getClasses(this.motCle,this.page,this.size)
  .subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(data);
    this.listClasses=data;
    this.pages=new Array<number>(data['totalPages']);
    console.log(this.pages);
  },err=>{
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

I want to get: "totalPages" in the image, like dimension of the Array. But I can not! Please, help me!:

[image]

Comment: I can not insert the image

Comment: which log is it in the image?

Comment: Is there someone to help me, thank you!

Comment: the log in the image = console.log(data)

Answer (score 1):

The totalPages information is in the page property of your data, as shown in your image, so you need to access it like this :

```
this.pages=new Array<number>(data.page.['totalPages']);
```

Comment: Thank you, but, i have error like : TS2339:Property 'page' does not exist on type 'Objet"

Comment: I do not always understand where the error comes from. Does anyone have an idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to access properties like this -

```
this.pages = data['page']['totalPages']
console.log(this.pages)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have  : [ error TS2339: Property 'pages' does not exist on type 'Object'.]

Comment: Please accept the answer as it provides the correct solution to your problem. That's how we do it here in SO.

Comment: Yes, solution UPDATE from Holydragon2 is CORRECT, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

give a try to this @Anteseva ,

> do some changes like below

```
this.classeService.getClasses(this.motCle,this.page,this.size)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.listClasses = data;
        this.pages = new Array<number>(data.page.totalPages);
        console.log(this.pages);
      },err=>{
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```